# Validate class/method names with regex

Tags: php, regex, object, methods

I'm currently working on an MVC Style framework for a company and for security reasons I need to make sure that the controller / method that's passed via the Query String is valid chars to the RFC (which I can't find).

I need to be able to validate / sanitize class names according to what's allowed by the PHP interpreter

For Example:

```
class SomEFunk__YClAssName extends Controller
{

}
```

I need some kind of regex that will validate `SomEFunk__YClAssName` and sanitize it if need be! This is also the same principles as methods.

There is a few things to take into consideration such as

- Numerics at the start
- Only underscores allowed
- Certain PHP Special Chars to be allowed.

Any information on this or possible expressions would be really helpful.

Here is some of my Router Code so you can see where I need to implement it:

```
private function prepareQueryString()
    {
        if(strlen($this->query_string) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Remove [ending|starting|multiple] slashes
        $this->query_string = preg_replace('/^\/+|\/+$|\/(?=\/)/', '', $this->query_string);
        foreach(explode('/',$this->query_string) as $Key => $Value)
        {
            if($Key == 0)
            {
                $Controller = $this->AssignController($Value);
            }
            if($Key == 1)
            {
                $this->AssignMethod($Value);
            }else
            {
                $this->AssignParam($Value);
            }
        }

        //Build RouterVar stdClass
    }

    public function AssignController(String $Controller)
    {
        if(!empty($Controller))
        {
            //Sanitize
        }
    }

    public function AssignMethod(String $Method)
    {
        if(!empty($Method))
        {
            //Sanitize
        }
    }

    public function AssignParam(String $Param)
    {
        $this->params[] = $Param;
    }
```

You will see the comment "Sanitize" where the check is needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the regex you're looking for short class name, e.g. `SomeClass` is:

```
<?php

preg_match(
    '/^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$/', 
    $input
);
```

According to: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

For namespaced class, e.g. `App\SomeClass` it is:

```
<?php

preg_match(
    '/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*(\\[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)*$/', 
    $input
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code example and documentation link. I'd have marked this as the answer.

Comment: **Attention**: I think there is a flaw in your `preg_match`, as no start/end delimiter is given. Your code with `$input="Definitely Not A Valid Classname!"` will return 1. If you change it to `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/', $input);` it returns 0.

Comment: Good call on the beginning/ending delimiter.

Comment: In case you want to validate a class name with namespace, use this: `/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*(\\[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)*$/` --- The difference is only in repeating the pattern with a backslash separator.

Comment: PHP website has been updated to `\x80` instead of `\x7f`. `^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$` and for @JosefKufner answer, the back slash should be 4. Example: `^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*(\\\\[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*)*$`

Answer (score 6):

You're better off using a very general regular expression, and then testing that the class exists with a simple call to `class_exists()`.

This will match any valid PHP class name, including really weird ones like `___` or `_3`, both of which are valid class names:

```
/^[a-z_]\w+$/i
```

I personally am more restrictive than PHP's naming conventions for classes.  I demand my controllers be capitalized, and post-fixed with `_controller` so that strange non-controller classes aren't invoked via weird URLs.  I'd use something like this:

```
class Products_controller extends Controller { }

// elsewhere, after parsing the controller name from the URI:

if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]\w+_controller$/', $controller_name)
&&  class_exists($controller_name)) {
  $controller = new $controller_name();
}
```

As an aside, passing the controller name via the query string yields really ugly and search-engine unfriendly URLs.  Consider building the controller name and method into the URL:

```
/products/index # controller=products, action=index
/users/show/3   # controller=users, action=show, user id=3
```

Comment: I come up with doing this `^(?=_*[A-z]+)[A-z0-9_]+$` but there are still chars that should be allowed for example `class €1{}` and `class €€_{}`

Comment: If you really want to invoke any arbitrarily named class, then literally all you care about is wither the class exists.  Skip the regular expression entirely, it's not adding anything security-wise, and just check `class_exists()`.

Comment: calling `class_exists` will invoke the autoloader.. and load the matching file... this can lead to side effects..  in a framework (I will not name), it's autoloader will load index.php if I do `class_exists('index')..  this will try to re-bootstrap the application and fatal error