# Mysql insert from XML with "hyphen" in field name

Tags: php, mysql, xml, insert

I am trying to insert into mysql from an xml using PHP, but the field name contains a "hyphen" and for some reason it is not inserting this field, the rest are fine. I have tried using the hex codes *x002D*, x2010,x2012, and none have worked. As you can see in my xml, the hyphen is not being changed like the space, but if I just remove the *x002D*  inserts everything after the "E" in other words just inserts -mail_x0020_Address.

This is my xml:

```
<encuestas>
<ID>9949</ID>
<E-mail_x0020_Address>email@email.com</E-mail_x0020_Address>
<ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code>90001</ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code>
</encuestas>
```

This is my insert statement ( I removed fields, I have 20 on that xml):

```
"INSERT INTO New_Encuestas_Datos(ID,`email`,`Zip/Postal Code`) VALUES('$product->ID','$product->E-mail_x0020_Address','$product->ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code')";
```

The variables are coming from an array reading the xml and like I said, everything  is imported except email. I have tried the following combinations:

E-mail_x0020_Address
E_x002D_mail_x0020_Address
E_x2010_mail_x0020_Address
E_x2012_mail_x0020_Address

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I doubt you can use it in a string, but in plain PHP it is `$product->{'E-mail_x0020_Address'};`. But that doesn't matter anyway, as you *should* escape you values prior to sending them to a database you can nicely name an escaped variable as you like.

Comment: I also tried yor solution, but I am getting a mysql syntax error. When you say escape, what are you refering exactly ( I am new to PHP and being honest I copied another part of the script and adapted to this xml file, but having problems with this email... )

Comment: As I said, you can't embed it in a string. You _should_ use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your all your values (not just the one with the `-` in it), because otherwise either an accidental or malicious `'` in your values would break the query. And then it's just `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($product->{'E-mail_x0020_Address'});`, and you can just use `$email` in the query as provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
"INSERT INTO New_Encuestas_Datos(ID,`email`,`Zip/Postal Code`) VALUES('{$product->ID}', '{$product->E-mail_x0020_Address}', '{$product->ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code}')";
```

**Edited:**

Just found here [Validate class/method names with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195614/validate-class-method-names-with-regex) that '-' is not valid in method names.

Comment: Not this specific case, of course, but yes, I'm using this way.

Comment: In that case, I'd like to know your PHP version, cause here it doesn't work, with the `-` being in the tagname and all.

Comment: 5.2.6 says the hosting panel, but I think I have been using this format for long time. Are you getting some specific error?

Comment: please not that this is not a simple _'how can I get an object variable in a string'_ question, but _'how can I get an object variable in a string when the variable name contains "-"'_ Could you run this code for me: http://codepad.org/3LlSI5ZD

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say I'm sure this will work in this specific case. I suggested trying with `{}` may solve the problem. I will try your sample. (And sorry about my English)

Comment: Your english is fine, I just wanna make damn sure it's not only here that I can't embed it in a string :P

Comment: @Wrikken I tried and couldn't do it either... Thanks for you persistency :D